# Correct XML creation of configuration variable in DocusignCLM workflow for Salesforce ETL step

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

Does anybody have corrected resources for how to do SOQL Queries in Salesforce using DocusignCLM Workflow, I have some resources (which seems to be wrong), I think they are internal once and I cant share it here.
It would be a great help anyone has a step by step approach to do Salesforce ETL to "Salesforce Org" from "DocusignCLM Workflow", using custom XML.

Comment: I am guessing that, everything is paid, nothing is free to learn...